# SQL JPA nativeQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa

I have a SQL nativQuery in my JPA app, that looks like that:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT user0_.USER_ID,
  user0_.FIRSTNAME,
  user0_.LASTNAME
FROM USERS user0_
WHERE user0_.USER_ID
      IN
      (SELECT
         app1_.user_id
       FROM applications app1_
       WHERE app1_.PROJECT_LOCATION_ID IN
             (SELECT
                pl3_.PROJECT_LOCATION_ID
              FROM project_locations pl3_
              WHERE pl3_.location_id IN
                    (SELECT
                       loco4_.LOCATION_ID
                     FROM locations loco4_
                     WHERE
                       ((6371 *
                         SQRT(POWER(RADIANS(loco4_.LATITUDE) - RADIANS(?), 2)
                              + POWER(
                             (RADIANS(loco4_.LONGITUDE) - RADIANS(?)) *
                             (COS((RADIANS(loco4_.LATITUDE) + RADIANS(?))/2)), 2))) <= ? ))));
```

this query gets me the users that applicated to assignment in some distance from a assignment location. It works just fine, but I would like to get the distance to, and that's my problem - I have no idea how to extract results of distance function at the end of the query.

I'm new to SQL and JPA so propably my problem is very easy to solve, but I can't figure it on my own.

Thanks in advance for help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I spend few hours, and beer on this one but I got it:) Now my query looks like:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT USR2.user_id, USR2.firstname, USR2.lastname, USR2.username, USD2.phone,
  min(6371 *
   SQRT(POWER(RADIANS(LOC2.LATITUDE) - RADIANS(LOC1.LATITUDE), 2)
        + POWER(
       (RADIANS(LOC2.LONGITUDE) - RADIANS(LOC1.LONGITUDE)) *
       (COS((RADIANS(LOC2.LATITUDE) + RADIANS(LOC1.LATITUDE))/2)), 2))) AS distance,
  GROUP_CONCAT(NO2.note) AS notes,
  max(APP2.CREATE_DATE) as last_user_app
FROM
  project_locations PRL1
  JOIN locations LOC1 ON PRL1.LOCATION_ID = LOC1.LOCATION_ID
  JOIN locations LOC2
    ON (6371 *
       SQRT(POWER(RADIANS(LOC2.LATITUDE) - RADIANS(LOC1.LATITUDE), 2)
            + POWER(
           (RADIANS(LOC2.LONGITUDE) - RADIANS(LOC1.LONGITUDE)) *
           (COS((RADIANS(LOC2.LATITUDE) + RADIANS(LOC1.LATITUDE))/2)), 2))) <= 22
  JOIN project_locations PRL2 ON PRL2.LOCATION_ID = LOC2.LOCATION_ID
  JOIN applications APP2 ON APP2.PROJECT_LOCATION_ID = PRL2.PROJECT_LOCATION_ID
  JOIN users USR2 ON USR2.user_id = APP2.user_id AND USR2.active = 1
  JOIN user_details USD2 ON USD2.USER_ID = USR2.USER_ID
  LEFT JOIN notes NO2 ON NO2.USER_ID = USR2.USER_ID
WHERE
   PRL1.PROJECT_LOCATION_ID = 46
GROUP BY USR2.user_id
```

by using JOIN instead of IN i got access to all data from joined tables, and speed of new query is much better that waterfall of nested IN's.
;0
Hope it'll help someone